# Use hyphen as word delimeter

Tags: solr

How to index 
    "multi-player"
as 
    "multi",
    "player",
    "multiplayer"

So i want for 
    "multi",
    "player",
    "multiplayer"

to include to results 
    "multi-player"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WordDelimiterFilterFactory in your analyzer for this term; by default, "multi-player" will be indexed as"multi" and "player". Add the option catenateWords="1" so that "multi-player" will also be indexed as "multiplayer". See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory for all the options.

Comment: Thank for replay. I see this options are enaled at schema.xml, but result is empty for search "multi":
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"
                preserveOriginal="1"/>

Comment: I use Apache Solr 3.6.2 from Drupal

Comment: not clear what might be going on; can you post the entire schema? If possible, first simplify the schema so that you have a single field that shows the problem. Also in your example - the searches for "player", "multiplayer", "multi-player" all work, it's just searching for "multi" that doesn't work?

Comment: To found item with "multi-player" i need type "multiplayer". "multi" and "player" return empty result.

Comment: How do you phrase your query, and what field do you query against? I tried analyzing "multi-player" for the "content" field, and it did index it as multi, player, multiplayer, multi-player. (check out the analysis tab in the Solr admin).